# Github bot - Unexpected token ; - Glitch

Tags: github, probot, github-bot, glitch.com

I'm trying to build my own github bot to cherry-pick pull-requests into release branches. There are several examples in Javascript/Typescript and using/not using [Probot](https://probot.github.io/docs/) ([Github](https://github.com/probot)) available on github:

- [Cherry-pick bot](https://github.com/googleapis/repo-automation-bots/tree/main/packages/cherry-pick-bot) (Typescript + Probot)
- [Here's some sort of guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/making-a-github-bot/)

At the moment I can successfully run my bot locally, but it's not working when deployed to Glitch.

### Here's what I did

```
npx create-probot-app issue_greeter
? App name: issue-greeter
? Description of app: Replies with a greeting when someone opens an issue
? Which template would you like to use? basic-ts => Comment on new issues - written in TypeScript
code issue_greeter
```

I want this bot to reside under my organization. So while normally you would do the following:

```
npm start
# Visit http://localhost:3000
> Register Github app
# Visit https://github.com/settings/apps/manifest
```

I'm doing this [manually](https://probot.github.io/docs/development/#manually-configuring-a-github-app):

- Visit [smee.io](https://smee.io)

[image: Smee.io - Start new channel]

- Click **Start a new channel**

  - Webhook Proxy URL = `https://smee.io/2TJ4whCGVUpsHdRr`
  - Webhook Secret = `bJpKnpXCsnhoJYU6O9Z5CEy6eSZ45tdP` (random string 1)
- Now move to the project. Copy `.env.example` as `.env` and paste the `WEBHOOK_PROXY_URL` and `WEBHOOK_SECRET`
- Visit the **Apps page** under your Github Organization (`https://github.com/organizations/ORGNAME/settings/apps`) and click **New GitHub App**

[image: New Github app]

[Here](https://pieterjandeclippel.medium.com/how-i-wrote-a-cherry-pick-bot-for-github-4819e07167cb) are all other instructions I did (and wrote down while doing them)

But for some reason my Glitch app won't start, and gives the following error:

[image: Glitch app for github bot]

There's no `WEBHOOK_PROXY_URL`, but a `WEBHOOK_URL` here (as per [instructions](https://probot.github.io/docs/deployment/#glitch)).

```
/rbd/pnpm-volume/725725db-f67a-46e6-9310-065c08ff5138/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache/9.1.2/node_modules/lru-cache/dist/cjs/index.js:27
        onabort;
               ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/rbd/pnpm-volume/725725db-f67a-46e6-9310-065c08ff5138/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/@octokit/auth-app/4.0.13/node_modules/@octokit/auth-app/dist-node/index.js:65:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

Note that the generated bundle is [already CommonJS](https://github.com/MintPlayer/issue_greeter/blob/master/tsconfig.json#L6)

- [Github repository](https://github.com/MintPlayer/issue_greeter)
- Node version: 10.24.1 ([which is like out-of-support for over 3 years by now](https://github.com/nodejs/Release/blob/main/schedule.json#L54))

[image: Node on Glitch]

What's causing this. I noted somewhere that Glitch seems to be using Node 10, but since everything is locally built that shouldn't be a problem?

Also, is the SMEE-channel still used when deployed to Glitch, or is this only for development?

Comment: You may want to try updating your Glitch app to use Node 16.x because the Probot docs say "recent version of Node" https://help.glitch.com/hc/en-us/articles/16287495688845-What-version-of-Node-can-I-use-and-how-do-I-change-update-upgrade-it-

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding `"engines": { "node": ">=16.x"` to the root `package.json`. This seems to be quite sensitive and you can't have spaces in the wrong places. But this seems to work. Now I just need to fix a `Error: Cannot find module './lib/index.js' from '/app'`

Comment: So it now seems that typescript compilation isn't working

Comment: Ah I see, in `.env` `NODE_ENV` must be set to `development` for `npm i` to install `typescript` and tsc to work. The app seems to run now, but does not yet seem to receive my git hooks